# SQL alphabetical query and display data from "name" column

Tags: mysql

How do i perform a query to obtain data from a row such that the column "name" has names that starts with alphabet 'A'?

This is what I have done so far:

`SELECT id, title, name, year,FROM table WHERE ?`
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL example:

```
SELECT id, title, name, year FROM table ORDER BY name
```

`ORDER BY` can be used to sort.

If you only want to have names beginning with `A`, use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT id, title, name, year FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'A%'
```

Comment: I'm not really sure which of the two you want.

Comment: the second option was the one i needed

Answer (score 0):

You could use

WHERE `name` LIKE 'A%'

Shai :)